# Type inference with union types - No best common type exists

Tags: typescript

So, I am playing with type inference in TypeScript. I will provide two examples that produces the same results when invoked, however in one of them TypeScript cannot infer the type due to "No best common type".

**Example with ternary operator**

```
function foo(a: boolean) {
    return a ? 4 : true;
}
```

The compiler infers that foo is `(a: boolean) => number | boolean` which is awesome.

**Example with if statement**

```
function foo(a: boolean) {
    if (a) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about "No best common type" when trying to infer return type. It confuses me that if statements should mess with the type inference. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error will be thrown when the return statements in a function do not have a common type. This can only happen when multiple return statements exist.

**First example - One return statement**

In the first example there is only one return statement that returns a value typed as `number | boolean` (parentheses added to emphasize this is one expression):

```
return (a ? 4 : true); // return number | boolean
```

That's fine. There's no other return statements the type needs to be in common with.

**Second example - Multiple return statements**

The second example has multiple return statements...

```
if (a) {
    return 4; // return number
} else {
    return true; // return boolean
}
```

... and no common type exists among the multiple statements. So it errors.

**Solution with multiple return statements**

When no common type exists between the return statements, you need to be explicit in order to let the compiler know you mean to do this:

```
function foo(a: boolean): number | boolean {
    if (a) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Related: See ["Best Common Type"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/805)

Comment: Yeah, I know type annotation helps here. So, what is the rationale behind from a compiler perspective?

Comment: @Peter I can't find anywhere to source this, but I'm pretty sure it does this in order to help prevent mistakes. Usually you want to return a common type from all the return statements... if you're not, then the code can become confusing.